# RGB values from NSColor

Tags: macos, cocoa, sketch-3, sketchapp, cocoascript

I'm attempting to read an osx colorlist (.clr), and having trouble interpreting the values of colors.

*context: I'm writing a color palette plugin for a design program called [Sketch](http://www.sketchapp.com/). The plugins are written in [cocoascript](https://github.com/ccgus/CocoaScript), which is a bridge between JS and Objective-C/Cocoa. This allows you to work with classes like NSColor*

I'm using this code to read the file:

```js
// Choose colorlist file ------------------------------------------

var openPanel = NSOpenPanel.openPanel();

openPanel.setCanChooseDirectories(true);
openPanel.setCanChooseFiles(true);
openPanel.setCanCreateDirectories(true);
openPanel.setTitle("Choose a file");
openPanel.setPrompt("Choose");
openPanel.runModal();

// Read colors from file ------------------------------------------

var filePath = openPanel.URLs().firstObject().path();
var fileName = filePath.lastPathComponent().stringByDeletingPathExtension();

var colorList = NSColorList.alloc().initWithName_fromFile(fileName, filePath);
var colorKeys = colorList.allKeys();
var color = colorList.colorWithKey(colorKeys[3]);    

log(color);
```

This works and I'm able to log the color to the OS X Console app. The problem is I'm not sure how to use the output:

```
NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0.0599575 0.220776 0.562826 1
```

the rgba value in CSS, Sketch, and Photoshop is

```
16, 77, 161, 1
```

I thought perhaps it just scaled the range from 255 to 1. But when I do the math it doesn't totally add up. The b value, for example:

```
0.562826 * 255 = 143.52063
```

but it should be 161.

Is there some other way I should be converting the color?

Comment: Why is this tagged Objective-C? The posted code is not Objective-C.

Comment: "rgba value in Sketch and Photoshop is 16, 77, 161, 1" RGB values without a color profile are almost entirely useless. You have to know what color profile those values are expressed relative to in order to make any sense of them. Read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30053097/1312143) for more.

Comment: @rmaddy Sketch Plugins are made possible by CocoaScript, a bridge that lets you use **Objective-C/Cocoa** code from an external script written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your `color` is a [NSColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000353-SW20) object, in `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace`, which is standard RGB color space. You can covert it to integer values by official method.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1576/_index.html

I transform that to CocoaScript for you.

```
var red = color.redComponent() * 255.99999;
var green = color.greenComponent() * 255.99999;
var blue = color.blueComponent() * 255.99999;
```