# Color picker on chrome gives wrong values

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, input, colors

I am using the input type="color". On Chrome and for the websafe colors I have a strange behavior. The color that is selected on the color picker is not the same as the output of the event, see below:

On the third tab of the color picker, change the selection to `web safe colors` and choose a color:

```js
jQuery('#color').change(function(e){
  console.log(e.target.value)
  jQuery('#result').val(e.target.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" id="color"/>

<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

The output is not the same as the selected value. The color-picker works correctly on Firefox. Any idea why Chrome has this behavior?

With the "third tab" I am referring to :

[image]

Comment: I get FF0080 for 255,000,128 in Chrome and FX - that seems correct. I do not get 3 tabs on it though

Comment: Same result as @mplungjan, No 3rd tab. and the color value seems to be correct when parsing the color code into online tools.  http://www.evernote.com/shard/s98/sh/be8295ed-0e5f-4253-90e6-7b520008ad98/9e002808833eeab045253e8af56e8a5a

Comment: @Christer @ mpungjan updated with screenshot. I am using mac.

Comment: Ah - missing information

Comment: So.. i managed to do this successfully on a mac i got, with the same result as OP. I just have an "idea", and that is substitution. It that it substitues the hex value with a fully web-supported hex value which might or might not be the exact same. If you select the #FFFFFF color, it returns the correct format, which leaves me with a conclusion that its working as designed.

Comment: @Christer I though the same but how can you explain that Firefox does not substitues ?

Comment: Does Firefox bring up the same dialog box? A browser can choose for themself if they want to implement the OS default colorpicker or if they want to use their own version. There are some other Stackoverflow posts regarding the color picker beeing different based on display settings in Chrome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050879/color-picker-on-mac-os-x-selects-wrong-colors

Comment: A bug was already filed. crbug.com/514425

Comment: @int32_t thx. I will leave the post open as reference.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome color picker works by taking color from current monitor **color profile**,and the problem may happens by changing color setting or sometime change monitor, please check the below method to solve.

Go to chrome://flags/#force-color-profile and click **Reset all to default**

Thanks.

Comment: Ta Muthu, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Even switching Chrome between monitors changed the value. Disabling 'Use hardware acceleration when available' under Settings -> System fixed the issue on Chrome v.62.0.3202.62

Answer (score 1):

Go to [chrome://flags/#force-color-profile](http://chrome://flags/#force-color-profile), change it to sRGB, and click the *Relaunch* button.

Answer (score -2):

maybe here my code will help you

```
$("#color").change(function(){console.log($(this).val());});
```